# Are these delegates garbage collected?

Tags: c#, delegates, garbage-collection

I have a class that exposes a method used to "register" delegates (these delegates are called as part of a later process). The delegate passed to the method is wrapped in a small object which is then added to a dictionary. The method looks a bit like this:-

```
public void Add(int id, Func<bool> someDelegate)
{
    var wrapper = new MyDelegateWrapper(someDelegate);
    _wrappers.Add(id, wrapper); // _wrappers is a Dictionary<>
}
```

Some time later, I might decide to "de-register" delegates by calling a method like this:-

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    _wrappers.Remove(id);
}
```

I'm curious to know whether this code introduces any GC issues. i.e. will it prevent either the "wrapper" object, or the object that created the delegate, from being GC'd? And does it make a difference whether the calling objects pass in an anonymous delegate or one of their own "real" methods?

Comment: Asking questions like this won't scale to every possible situation you'll encounter. If you care about memory leaks, *profile* your code and see if you have actual memory leaks.

Comment: Delegates are normal .net obejcts and they are GC'd and follow the same lifecycle as any other object, so no, the code you've provided does not introduce any GC issues. Both wrappers and delegates will be GC'd once no other object can call on them.

Answer (score 3):

Delegates are not COM objects. They do not need to implement `IDispose` and are garbage-collected when the GC deems appropriate to do so.

So as soon as they are no longer reachable from other .NET objects, they will be marked for collection, and will be collected when the CLR needs to clear space.

Answer (score 1):

The GC collects all object that have no *incoming* references from objects that are not to be collected. That is achieved by creating an object graph from all references on the stack and in static fields. If an object has an *outgoing* reference to another object, this does not prevent garbage collection.

When you add a handler to an event, this creates a reference from the object that contains the event to the object that contains the event listener. That does not prevent the object with the event to be collected.

The only exception is when you implement the event in method syntax (i.e. using `add` and `remove` methods) and create a reference from the listener to the object with the event handler in the `add` method. That however would be very unusual.